# how can I covert int to char in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to covert an `int` to `char`. Is there any way to do that?

For example:

```
{
    int i;
    char d;


    i = 55;
    d = i;

    printf("%c\n", d);

}
```

How do I make `d = 55`?

Comment: `d` _is_ 55. Just print it with the `%d` format.

Comment: is the code ascii of the char

Comment: What you want is to print an integer that represents an ascii character? Or converter an int into a string?

Comment: For the sake of compatibility with a computer internals, letters and other characters (also digits) are associated with a number, eg the char '7' is associated with 55, try 65 that should give you 'A' (see ASCII). Now the computer decides to print the number (55) or the character('7') depending on the format *you* require: giving 55 as argument, `printf` will display a number with format `%d`, and the char '7' with `%c`, ie the graphical representation associated with that number.

Comment: `char` is also an integer type, and the value 55 is representable as a `char`. What you get printed out depends on how you tell `printf` to interpret the value. `%c` says print out the glyph corresponding to the value (if there is one), `%d` says print out the integer value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put the number 55 into a string, use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed your example can do what you want.

If you really want to place safe, you may:

```
d = (char) i;
```

Comment: i already is an int. I think you mean `d = (char) i;`. However the way the OP has written it you will at least get a compiler warning saying that you might lose data, whereas if you specify the cast the compiler trusts that you know what you are doing...

Comment: oh typo. indeed I don't understand what is he asking...

Answer (score 1):

Try this code segment:
printf("%d\n", d);

Answer (score 0):

char are presented in the memory as binary format wich is equivalent to a number and this number is called a code ascii. when you print the code ascii with "%c" Then it will print the charchter equivalent to this code ascii